# TinyMCE and Drupal css problems

Tags: drupal, tinymce, wysiwyg

I have problems with my wysiwyg editor in drupal (TinyMCE).

I have selected the theme stylesheet for my TinyMCE-editor, but some things still don't show up the way they should. For instance, the space below a paragraph does not match in the editor, leading to my users making extra line feeds in the editor, which of course results in excessive space between lines once the page is viewed by visitors.

Below are two images attached - first one in edit mode, second image shows what really happens... how can I make the edit mode represent my stylesheet's P-tag margins etc.?

http://hemsida.enkelw.se/edit.png

http://hemsida.enkelw.se/view.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the theme stylesheet you can still override css using the tinymce init parameter [content_css](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3acontent_css). This setting alows you to add a css file to the editors iframe head correcting/changing the appearance of the html presented. Her is an example:

```
content_css: "http://myserver/css//tiny_special.css",
```

To find out what css settings you need or need to correct Firebug may be of help.

Comment: glad it works for you, in that case i suggest you accept this answer (and you may upvote it)